# Add one more tab into accordion menu, bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use one boostrap snippet for accordion menu https://s.bootsnipp.com/iframe/VgZb. I have extracted code from this page and want to add one more tab for menu but I can't. I have tried to copy div selection and make div with id collapseFive but not working. Someone to help ? Thanks.

```
<div class="container"><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close">
                        </span>Clients</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Create clients</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash text-success"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">View clients</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                        </span>Campaigns</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Orders</a> <span class="label label-success">$ 320</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Invoices</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Shipments</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Tex</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                        </span>Statistics</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Change Password</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Notifications</a> <span class="label label-info">5</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Import/Export</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="text-danger">
                                        Delete Account</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                        </span>Account</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Change password</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Notifications</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Change password</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Notifications</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                    if ($_SESSION["userStatus"] == "superadmin") {
                        echo '<div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"><table class="table">';
                        echo '<tr><td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Change password</a>';
                        echo '</td></tr><tr><td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Notifications</a>';
                        echo '</td></tr></table></div></div>';
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add another pane you'll want this focus of code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          Campaigns
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change the `href="#"` in the `panel-title` to reflect the change needed in the second div on the panel. So in my example the `panel-collapse` has the `id="collapseFive"` and in which case I updated the `panel-heading a` tag to have an `href="#collapseFive"`.

Hopefully I understood what you were asking for.

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks. But there is small problem, when i click on other pane this pane don't collapse like other do.

Comment: Can you tell me where, or show me where you are inserting this code? When I run your code and mine, they work. [See here](https://www.bootply.com/1bAdRVYLKt)

Comment: after div id="collapseFour"

Comment: Take a look again at my answer. If you put the code after the collapseFour panel-header, you'll see that it works. What you did was instead, made it a new item in panel-body. So each `panel panel-default` is an accordion item.

Comment: Small correction, when i click on pane, pane opens, but when i click on other pane previous pane won't close. For example, when I click on first pane, this pane is opened, when I click on second pane, second pane is opened and first is closed, but with this pane this is not a case. This is a problem.